# Why IMG load everytime when refresh the web page?

Tags: html, css

I have one html page which contains background images + one logo (image). I called background-images through external css file, but for the logo, i used with an `<image>` tag. Whenever I refresh the page, the logo image is always reloaded but not the background images are. Can i know why the image reload every time ? Do i need to use that logo image as background-image as well ? Any suggestion please.

Comment: What browser do you use? What caching headers do you use?

Comment: And how are you refreshing? F5 or Ctrl+F5?

Comment: Tell us what's the response header information is. Probably server don't tell browser to cache image...

Comment: sorry for uninformative post. for browsers, i tested with all latest browsers. All got same result. I tried both F5 and Refresh button from browser. It's always reloading also. And in my localhost, it's fine, it's not always reloaded. But when i put it into live server, it's always reloading. How can i declare caching headers ?

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver should return headers to assist client-side caching. They are not doing that by default. Google for mod_expire if you are under Apache.

Comment: How can i achieve it ? Please kindly guide me. Thanks.